# transparent separator line based on nsbox

Tags: cocoa, nsbox

I have a problem with separator line, it is based on `NSBox`, I use a regular `NSBox` with its Box Type set to "Custom" and border type set to "Groove".

In the case of not painting the background, it's fine.

But if to draw the background, Can not be a transparent background

How to implement like transparent background effect?

Like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by setting color with alpha like this:

```
[boxOutlet setFillColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];
```

It will fill `NSBox` with black 50% transparency. **Alpha is opacity value.**
**Note:** *boxOutlet* is IBOutlet of `NSBox`.

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: hi,Justin Boo.thanks for your reply.but it seem difference with my fanciful effect.I just want to Draw a separator line in a background image, it keep original solid effect.

Comment: @user1414516 then You need to post Your code and screenshot. Because it's hard to understand what You need.

Comment: http://b219.photo.store.qq.com/psb?/V13URhpd0C6SQx/YiIEENKK2OfUlVDL8X1k2gXL70wV.3VU4eKv0fpSowU!/b/YTNXioKSPgAAYpJTjYJjPgAA

Comment: http://b219.photo.store.qq.com/psb?/V13URhpd0C6SQx/YiIEENKK2OfUlVDL8X1k2gXL70wV.3VU4eKv0fpSowU!/b/YTNXioKSPgAAYpJTjYJjPgAA

Comment: I will add this to Your question, but... I can't understand what You want.. ?? Explain more, what is in that screenshot? image behind NSBox or in it? Text? MAybe You are talking about border??

Comment: hi,Justin Boo.i already implement this effect.use a picture for it.thanks again for your eagerness.